# How to get all possibilities for required and optional entries?

Tags: arrays, string

The title is not very explicit :')

So there is an example to understand what I want to do :

I have to put a string (as input) which have to look like:

```
(Hey) (how are you) !
```

This have to create this string array:

```
!
Hey !
how are you !
Hey how are you !
```

Based on the parentheses that have to made all possibilities of string, considering that parenthesis is "optional"

Comment: Please read the tag descriptors before using a tag, and don’t spam tags which have no bearing on your question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function combs(arr, depth) {
    var resp = [], len = arr.length, total = (1 << len);
    for (var i = 1; i < total; i++) {
        var tmp = [], good = true;
        for (var k = 0; k < len; k++) {
            if ((i & (1 << k))) {
                tmp.push(arr[k]);
            }
            if (depth && tmp.length > depth) {
                good = false;
                continue;
            }
        }
        good && resp.push(tmp);
    }
    return resp;
}

const entries = [{c:"hey",r:false}, {c:" how are you",r:false}, {c:"!",r:true}];

entries.forEach((v,i)=>entries[i].i=i);

const req = entries.filter(v=>v.r);
const opt = entries.filter(v=>!v.r);

const result = [req.map(v=>v.c).join("")];

combs(opt).forEach(v=>{
    result.push(req.concat(v).sort((a,b)=>a.i-b.i).map(v=>v.c).join(""))
})

console.log(result)
```

Firstly, I have to calculate the possibility of having only required elements,
after I calculate all possibility for optional elements only, and I merge each optional possibilities with the only required possibility.
I sort by the index in the origin array.

And I get:

```js
[ '!', 'hey!', ' how are you!', 'hey how are you!' ]
```

As wanted :)